# How to replace a pointer value with a variable in sql xml?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I need to write a WHILE loop and pass a variable to an xml query:

Given this logic:

```
DECLARE @count INT = 0;
DECLARE @pointer INT = 0;
DECLARE @pointer_str varchar(100);

DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = '<SampleXML>
                <Colors>
                <Color1>White</Color1>
                <Color2>Blue</Color2>
                <Color3>Black</Color3>
                <Color4 Special="Light">Green</Color4>
                <Color5>Red</Color5>
                </Colors>
                <Colors>
                <Color1>White</Color1>
                <Color2>Blue</Color2>
                <Color3>Black</Color3>
                <Color4 Special="Light">Green</Color4>
                <Color5>Red</Color5>
                </Colors>
            </SampleXML>'

SET @count = 
    (
        SELECT
            a.b.value('count(/SampleXML/Colors)', 'int')
        FROM 
            @MyXML.nodes('data') a(b)
    )

WHILE @count < @pointer
    BEGIN   
        SELECT
            a.b.value('Colors[' + @pointer + ']/Color1[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color1
        FROM 
            @MyXML.nodes('SampleXML') a(b);

        SELECT @pointer = @pointer + 1;
    END
```

I am trying to get the following variable in a SELECT statement to parse XML but I receive the following error:

```
The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal.
```

Also, when I pass it the literal value of '1', I can't see the select being run inside the loop.  can someone please help me?

Comment: Your loop will create multiple result sets. Is that what you want? If not, could you update your answer with what you want the end result to be given your sample XML?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to write a WHILE loop and pass a variable to an xml query:

In XML.value() method, you can refer to a variable `varName` as `sql:variable("@varName")`.

Regarding your question, it appeard to me that you are trying extract the text within `Color1` nodes in your XML. The following SQL does that:

```
DECLARE @count INT = 0;
DECLARE @pointer INT = 0;
DECLARE @pointer_str varchar(100);

DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = '<SampleXML>
        <Colors>
        <Color1>White</Color1>
        <Color2>Blue</Color2>
        <Color3>Black</Color3>
        <Color4 Special="Light">Green</Color4>
        <Color5>Red</Color5>
        </Colors>
        <Colors>
        <Color1>Green</Color1>
        <Color2>Blue</Color2>
        <Color3>Black</Color3>
        <Color4 Special="Light">Green</Color4>
        <Color5>Red</Color5>
        </Colors>
    </SampleXML>'

SELECT @count = count(a.b.query('.')) FROM @MyXml.nodes('/SampleXML/Colors') as a(b)

SELECT
    a.b.value('.', 'varchar(10)')
FROM 
    @MyXML.nodes('/SampleXML/Colors/Color1') a(b);
```

It produces the output as

```
----------
White
Green

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what if i need each value as a column

Comment: If Color1, Color2 etc., were attributes of `<Color>` node, then it would be easier to straightaway select them. Now it would be difficult to get them into a column each in a single query. Either you should write multiple queries to get each list of colors or convert into attributes and get it at a single go, afaik.

Comment: @some_bloody_fool, you may be interested in this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192398/select-xml-nodes-as-rows?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: You, sir, are awesome for this! It took quite a while to find this for my needs. Thank you!